# Gtk Python Callback

Tags: python, callback, gtk

probably I'm less than a newbie in both python and GTK. Here my problem:
I've created a class to display a windows with a search bar and a treeview.
I fill the tree reading from an SQLITEDB.

Fine.

I'd like to use the search bar in order to select an item in the treeview (so performing, a db search and fill the treeview with the result)

I'm blocked on the callback since I cannot understand how to pass the user inserted data to a specific function.
Below some lines from my (STUPID) code.

```
class SecondWin:
    def __init__(self):
        self.win = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
        self.win.connect("delete_event", self.delete_event)
        self.win.set_title("Gmail Phonebook")
        self.win.set_size_request(600, 300) #Larghez1za, Altezza
        self.win.set_border_width(8)
        self.win.set_position(gtk.WIN_POS_CENTER)
        self.win.connect("destroy", self.destroy)

        self.table = gtk.Table(8, 8,True)

        self.cerca_bottone = gtk.Button("Cerca")
        self.cerca_bottone.set_size_request(70, 30) #Larghezza, Altezza
        self.cerca_bottone.connect( "clicked", self.cercainrubrica) #Call back sul bottone
        self.table.attach(self.cerca_bottone, 0, 1, 0, 1,gtk.SHRINK,gtk.SHRINK)

#       Search BAR
        self.hbox = gtk.HBox()
        self.entry = gtk.Entry(30) 
        self.entry.connect("activate", self.cercainrubrica) #call back su enter
        self.hbox.pack_end(self.entry)
        self.table.attach(self.hbox, 1, 8, 0, 1,gtk.EXPAND|gtk.FILL|gtk.SHRINK,
                      gtk.EXPAND|gtk.FILL|gtk.SHRINK,0,0)

        self.vbox = gtk.VBox(False, 8)
        self.sw = gtk.ScrolledWindow()
        self.sw.set_shadow_type(gtk.SHADOW_ETCHED_IN)
        self.sw.set_policy(gtk.POLICY_AUTOMATIC, gtk.POLICY_AUTOMATIC)
        self.vbox.pack_start(self.sw, True, True, 0)
        self.table.attach(self.vbox, 1, 8, 1, 9,gtk.EXPAND|gtk.FILL|gtk.SHRINK,
                      gtk.EXPAND|gtk.FILL|gtk.SHRINK,10,10)  

        rubrica=mydb.find_record_complex("%", colonne_test[0]) 

        store = self.create_model(rubrica) #THIS WORK FINE DISPLAYING THE SELECTION

        HERE MY FUNCION

        self.cercainrubrica ??

        treeView=gtk.TreeView(store)
        treeView.connect("row-activated", self.on_activated)
        treeView.set_rules_hint(True)
        self.sw.add(treeView)
        self.create_columns(treeView,nomi_colonne)
        self.statusbar = gtk.Statusbar()



        self.win.add(self.table)
        self.win.show_all()

THIS IS MY CALL BACK
    def cercainrubrica( self, w, data=None):
        name = self.entry.get_text()
        capperi=mydb.find_record_complex(name, colonne_test[0]) 
        store = self.create_model(capperi)

        return store



    def delete_event(self, widget, event, data=None):
        return gtk.FALSE
    def destroy(self, widget, data=None):
        return gtk.main_quit()
    def main(self):
        gtk.main()
    def create_model(self,records):
        store = gtk.ListStore(str, str, str,str)

        for record in records:
            store.append([record[1], record[2], record[3],record[4]])

        return store

    def create_columns(self, treeView,intestazione_colonne):

        i = 0
        for nomecolonna in intestazione_colonne:
            rendererText = gtk.CellRendererText()
            column = gtk.TreeViewColumn(intestazione_colonne[i], rendererText, text=i)
            column.set_sort_column_id(i)    
            treeView.append_column(column)
            i += 1

    def on_activated(self, widget, row, col):

        model = widget.get_model()
        text = model[row][0] + ", " + model[row][1] + ", " + model[row][2]
        self.statusbar.push(0, text)    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    second = SecondWin()
    second.main()
```

ANY HELP IS REALLY APPRECIATED

Comment: I have no idea what you want. Please clarify your question removing code and comments that aren't related to the problem and creating a minimal testcase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure what you want to do but if you want to filter what the treeview is showing based on the entered text, you should take a look at [GtkTreeModelFilter](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/unstable/GtkTreeModelFilter.html). You can use it as a TreeModel and set your own VisibleFunc that decides if a row should be visible or not based on the entered text. When the text changes, just call refilter(): that will call VisibleFunc() for every row.

Sorry for not having a python example or docs for you, I hope that still helps...

Comment: To use a GtkTreeModelFilter you would have to fetch *all* rows first, that might not be a bad idea depending on what OP is working on.